# Integral over set of measure zero.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:(X,\eta,\mu)\to [0,\infty]$ measurable and $E\in\eta$ with $\mu(E)=0$ ($\eta$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu$ a positive measure).
Then $\displaystyle\int_E f\,d\mu=0$.

We have  $$\int_E f\,d\mu=\sup\left\{\int_E s\,d\mu\ : \ s \text{ is a measurable simple function }, s\leq f \right\} \tag{*}.$$

But if $s$ is simple (and measurable) then $s=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\chi_{E_i}$, with $E_i\in\eta$.

Now

$$\int_E s\,d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\mu(E\cap E_i)=0,$$

because $E\cap E_i \subseteq E \Rightarrow \mu(E\cap E_i)\leq \mu(E)=0$.

So that, for all simple function $s\leq f$ , we have  $\displaystyle\int_E s\,d\mu=0$, therefore $\displaystyle\int_E f\,d\mu=0$

Is this correct?

Thank you all.

Comment: Looks fine. Alternatively, $0 \leq f \leq \infty$ so $$0 \leq \int_Ef\ d\mu \leq \int_E\infty\ d\mu = \infty m(E) = 0.$$

Comment: Your proof is really nice and straightforward.  Good job!

Comment: I try not to use $\infty \times 0  = 0$