# Calculation of $\mathbb{E}(1(X_i = X_j))$ and its estimation

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

My question is the following. Suppose $X_1, X_2,...$ are iid draws from an exponential distribution. Then
$$ \mathbb{E}(1(X_i = X_j)) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty 1(u = q) \lambda e ^{-\lambda u} \lambda e^{-\lambda q} \,du\, dq = \int_0^\infty \lambda^2 e^{-2 \lambda u}\, du = \frac{\lambda}{2} $$
However my intuition says that the probability of drawing two identical numbers from a continuous distribution should be zero. To check this I am trying to estimate this expectation. If I am not mistaken, an unbiased estimator would be the following U-statistic
$$ U_n = \binom{n}{2}^{-1} \sum_c 1(x_i = x_j) $$
Where $c$ is the set of all combinations $\{i,j\}$ with $i \neq j$ from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. However when I try to compute this estimate the result is always zero regardless of sample size. Is there any mistake in the computation of the expectation? Is this expectation $0$ or $\frac{\lambda}{2}$? in case it is the latter how do I estimate it?
In case it helps here is a piece of code showing how I compute the estimate.

```
N = 1000;           %Sample size
U = rand(N,1);      %Generate sample from uniform distribution
lambda = 1;         
X = -log(U)/lambda; %Generate sample from exponential distribution

%Compute the estimate
y = 0;
for i=1:N-1
    for j = i+1:N
    y = y + (X(i) == X(j));
    end
end
U_n = (2/(N*(N-1)))*y;
```

Comment: The right result I think should be zero. I think you are confusing the indicator function with the delta function. To see that they are different, just think of the Dirac $\delta(x)$ function (distribution) as a limit of functions with integral one and localized at $0$. In the limit they have to get an infinite value at 0 to keep the normalization. The indicator function $1_{\{x=0\}}$ does nothing like that: after integration shall not get a value of one, but the measure of the set (in this case, zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had a mistake in

$$ \mathbb{E}(1(X_i = X_j)) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty 1(u = q) \lambda e ^{-\lambda u} \lambda e^{-\lambda q} \,du\, dq = \int_0^\infty \lambda^2 e^{-2 \lambda u}\, du = \frac{\lambda}{2} $$

when $u=q$ you  correctly replace $q$ by $u$ in 
$$\lambda e ^{-\lambda u} \lambda e^{-\lambda q}$$. I think the mistake happen
when you applied condition $u=q$ in

$$\int_{u\in (0,\infty)}\int_{q\in (0,\infty)}$$

this be

$$\int_{u\in (0,\infty)}\int_{q\in (u,u)}$$(area such that

$$u\in (0,\infty) \hspace{.8cm} q\in (0,\infty) \hspace{.8cm} u=q$$

is a line! and the measure of it is zero)

We know

$\int_{q\in (u,u)}f dq=0$ since

$\int_{A}f dq=0$ when $m(A)=0$.(integrals over $A$ such that $A$ have zero measure is zero 
 [integral-over-set-of-measure-zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922096/integral-over-set-of-measure-zero)) so

$$ \mathbb{E}(1(X_i = X_j)) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty 1(u = q) \lambda e ^{-\lambda u} \lambda e^{-\lambda q} \,du\, dq $$

$$=\int_{u\in (0,\infty)}\int_{q\in (u,u)} \lambda e ^{-\lambda u} \lambda e^{-\lambda q} \,du\, dq=0$$